# Watin can't find element when running outside main thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, watin

The problem is with the button:contains('Deal') selector, the button containing deal does exist on the page and Watin can find it without problems when running in main thread.

```
    // Add bet, deal cards and wait for animation
    private void dealCards()
    {
        // Start the game if chip exists
        if (browser.Image(Find.BySrc(chipURL)).Exists)
        {
            browser.Image(Find.BySrc(chipURL)).Click();

            // This is where the thread stops

            browser.Button(Find.BySelector("button:contains('Deal')")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(dealCardsAnimationTime);

            if (Convert.ToInt32(browser.Span(Find.ByClass("player-points")).Text) == 21)
            {
                consoleTextBox.AppendText("You won by blackjack.");
                gameOver = true;
            }

            return;
        }
    }
```

Update:

Browser is a Internet Explore window that I interact with using WatiN, other than the UI changes, the problem seems to be that WatiN can't find the button.

However it's still somewhat related to multithreading, as the same code works fine without multithreading and the element that it's searching for does exist.

Update 2: Changed title and description of problem as the old one appeared to be unrelated.

Context ( in case it's necessary )

```
    // When bet button is clicked
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        blackjackThread = new Thread(blackjackGame);

        if (dealInProgress == false)
        {
            blackjackThread.Start();
            // blackjackGame();
        }
    }

    // Blackjack deal handler
    private void blackjackGame()
    {

        consoleTextBox.AppendText("\r\n");
        resetVariables();
        dealCards();

        if (gameOver == true)
        {
            checkResult();
            dealInProgress = false;
            blackjackThread.Abort();
            return;
        }

        checkCards();
        logPoints();

        while (gameOver == false)
        {
            botAction();
        }

        checkResult();
        dealInProgress = false;
        blackjackThread.Abort();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: `consoleTextBox.AppendText` looks like it's modifying the UI... you can't do that from a non-UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't know that. However the thread stops before that, it doesn't click the deal button.

Comment: Well again, if `browser` is part of the UI (you haven't told us *anything* about what kind of app this is) then manipulating that in the wrong thread will probably fail too...

Comment: The browser is a internet explorer window, I am using Watin to interact with it. Since it manages to click on the chip it seems like it works with my thread.

Comment: I strongly suspect an exception is being thrown somewhere. I'd expect that to be shown when you run the code in your debugger. (As an aside, now would be a good time to start adopting .NET naming conventions...)

Comment: When u click the `image` any new tab/window opens up? and you are trying to find the button on the older window? which might be causing the issue!